# Why does this paper claim to have found a minimal width of $d_{in}+1$?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Why does [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.11278.pdf) (click the link) claim to have found a minimal width of $d_{in}+1$ in the abstract? I mean, if you read the main result, it seems like they only find a universal approximator with width $d_{in} + d_{out}$. What am I missing or did they make a mistake? I do not completely understand all the math but I do think I get the gist of it, and also $d_{in}+1$ is not even mentioned when showing a bound of the difference between the function approximated by the neural network and the actual function...

Comment: In case nobody answers I'd suggest asking on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ which tends to be more oriented towards theoretical questions like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the abstract of the paper:

> Specifically, we answer the following question: for a fixed $d_{in} \ge 1$,
> what is the minimal width $w$ so that neural nets with ReLU
> activations, input dimension $d_{in}$, hidden layer widths at most $w$,
> and arbitrary depth can approximate any continuous, real-valued
> function of $d_{in}$ in variables arbitrarily well?

"Real-valued function" means that the output dimension $d_{out}=1$. Their Theorem 1 is more general and says that for any $d_{in}, d_{out} \ge 1$ you will need $d_{in}+1 \le w \le d_{in}+d_{out}$.